# Simple Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch computation with relative Todd class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, chern-classes, grothendieck-riemann-roch

$\DeclareMathOperator\Tot{Tot}\DeclareMathOperator\ch{ch}\DeclareMathOperator\td{td}\DeclareMathOperator\ker{ker}\DeclareMathOperator\rk{rk}$I was wondering if the following is correct: Let $X=\Tot(L)$ be the total space of a line bundle $L$ on a smooth projective surface $Y$. Let $i: Y \subset X$ be the embedding of $Y$ as the zero section and $E$ a vector bundle on $Y$. I want to compute the Chern classes of $i_*E$, which is a $2$-dimensional sheaf on the threefold $X$.
I think the easiest thing is using this version of Grothendieck-Riemann–Roch $$\ch(i_*E)=i_*(\ch(E)\td(T_i))$$ where $T_i$ is $\ker(T_Y \rightarrow T_X|_Y)$. As $T_X|_Y\cong T_Y\oplus L $, I think $\td(T_i)=\td(L)^{-1}$. Is this true? So in this case I compute $\ch(E)=(\rk(E)+c_1+1/2(c_1^2-2c_2))$ against  $$\td(T_i)=(1+c_1(L)/2+c_1^2(L)/12)^{-1}=1-c_1(L)/2+c_1^2(L)/6-c_1(L)^3/24$$
thanks!